# Need to send a mail (bash or php script) using "sendmail" of a different linux server

Tags: linux, sendmail

Any means of specifying the IP address we want to connect to send that mail.?

Comment: You could try using the sendmail proxy feature?

Answer (score 1):

Use PHP`s PEAR library class [Mail](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail). It's really straightforward.

Example:
(it's using remote SMTP server with SMTP AUTH, you don't need to use it)

```
<?php
 require_once "Mail.php";

 // mail data
 $from = "You <sender@example.com>";
 $to = "Her <recipient@example.com>";
 $subject = "Hi!";
 $body = "Hi,\n\nHow are you?";

 // SMTP server info
 $host = "mail.example.com";
 $username = "smtp_username";
 $password = "smtp_password";

 // create mail headers
 $headers = array(
   'From' => $from,
   'To' => $to,
   'Subject' => $subject);

 // create PEAR Mail object passing SMTP server info
 $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
   array (
     'host' => $host,
     'auth' => true,
     'username' => $username,
     'password' => $password));

 // send the email
 $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

 // check the result
 if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
   echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
 } else {
   echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
 }
?>
```